# How do I merge multiple rows with partial duplicated data into one row but keep non-duplicated data?

Tags: linq, datatable, merge

I got a big datatable (over 300K rows with 40 columns in it) with data, the fragments like these (all value is string) :

> colA colB colC ColD ColdE ColF ColG ColH
>   --------------------------------------------------------
>   A01  B01   C01  DA1 EA1 FA1 GA1 HA1
>   A01  B01   C01  DA2 EA2 FA2 GA2 HA2
>   A02  B02   C02  DA3 EA3 FA3 GA3 HA3
>   A02  B02   C02  DA4 EA4 FA4 GA4 HA4
>   A03  B03   C03  DA5 EA5 FA5 GA5 HA5
>   A04  B04   C04  DA6 EA6 FA6 GA6 HA6

There is partial data duplicated and I would like merge duplicated data by using colA + ColB+ ColC for key and keep ColD ColE ColF, use first row for other columns. The expected result like these:

> colA colB colC ColD1 colE1 colF1 colG1 ColD2 colE2 colF2 colG2 ColH
>   ------------------------------------------------
>   A01  B01  C01   DA1   EA1 FA1 GA1 DA2 EA2 FA2 GA2 HA1
>   A02  B02  C02   DA3   EA3 FA3 GA3 DA4 EA4 FA4 GA4 HA3
>   A03  B03  C03   DA5   EA5 FA5 GA5 null null null null HA5
>   A04  B04  C04   DA6   EA6 FA6 GA6 null null null null HA6

It is something like pivot but have some difference, I tried to use T-SQL or LINQ with C# but have no idea to do this, please someone help, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a job for the [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

relying on the input records you've provided

```
var input = new DataTable();
input.Columns.Add("ColA");
input.Columns.Add("ColB");
input.Columns.Add("ColC");
input.Columns.Add("ColD");
input.Rows.Add("A01", "B01", "CA1", "DA1");
input.Rows.Add("A01", "B01", "CA2", "DA2");
input.Rows.Add("A02", "B02", "CA3", "DA3");
input.Rows.Add("A02", "B02", "CA4", "DA4");
input.Rows.Add("A03", "B03", "CA5", "DA5");
input.Rows.Add("A04", "B04", "CA6", "DA6");
```

you could convert a record into a dynamic expandable object

```
public IDictionary<string, Object> Map(DataRow row)
{
    var columns = row.Table.Columns;
    var result = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
    for (var index = 0; index < row.ItemArray.Count(); index++)
    {
        result.Add($"{columns[index]}", row[index]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then a bit of logic meant to group input by marker element and expand where needed

```
var seed = new List<IDictionary<string, Object>>();
var output = input
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(Map)
    .Aggregate(seed, (results, current)=>
    {
        // Check if the current values match any of the first element in the results
        var query = from result in results
                    let marker = result
                        .Select(p => p.Value)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
                    where current.Values.Contains(marker)
                    select result;

        var found = query.SingleOrDefault();
        if (found == null)
        {
            // None were found then simply append the current values
            results.Add(current);
        }
        else
        {
            // Some were found then isolate the new ones
            var others = from value in current.Values
                         where !found.Values.Contains(value)
                         select value;

            // Append the new ones to the found result
            foreach (var value in others)
            {
                var index = found.Values.Count;
                found.Add($"Col{index}".ToString(), value);
            }
        }

        return results;
    });
```

and the end result will look like this

[image]

check [gist](https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/fd30e413efd50d1cbcc787ed5b5ca813#file-47789723-3-cs) for the whole picture

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've update my question try to make clearer, could you help please?

Comment: Can you be more specific? This solution produces the expectated outcome. Or isn't it?

Comment: I could not replace input from your sample to a datatable, there is a error like "cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly", and I would need keep column name for covert result back to datatable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you've hijacked the scope of the question and shifted it towards datatables with you edits :)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47789723/revisions

Comment: nevertheless see my updated answer that makes use of a datatable as data input

Comment: Sorry, I have problem on compiling, vs2010 alert me that An unexpected character '$' at $"Col{index}" , could you help please? thank you.

Comment: That's mostly because i am using interpolated strings, a feature that is available in C# 6 and later versions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings
This feature must have been introduced in .net world only starting with .net 4.6 if i am recollecting well.
As you rely on VS2010 and datatables there are high chances that you are targeting an inferior version of .net.

Comment: Replace string interpolation with string.Format to overcome the issue

Comment: I've tried a set of real data, but there is some merge problem. It merge some data but is not duplicated. If I could use 2 column (SN+NO) for key to decide  should be merge or not, how do I change the LINQ syntax to do it? thank you.

Comment: this sounds like a new question to me, feel free to provide a specific set of data for it, and somebody might help again. In the end you need to decide if for the provided question, any given answers resolves the problem you have raised. Specifying an input and an output is great thing to start with but there is no way i could grasp the entire complexity of your own project, so i can only answer focused on what was asked in the first place :)

Comment: I've updated the question again, and if you free please help me about it, or I should open another question for it? thanks for your help and patient.

Comment: see an updated gist, relying on the input you've provided https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/fd30e413efd50d1cbcc787ed5b5ca813#file-stack-47789723-3-cs hope it helps to work it out from here

Comment: +1 Much much better answer than mine! I didn't know the `ExpandoObject`, your answer is useful to both OP and me :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is **not** a generic solution but will work in the given example.

```
List<string[]> input = new List<string[]>()
{
    new string[] {"A01","B01","CA1","DA1"},
    new string[] {"A01","B01","CA2","DA2"},
    new string[] {"A02","B02","CA3","DA3"},
    new string[] {"A02","B02","CA4","DA4"},
    new string[] {"A03","B03","CA5","DA5"},
    new string[] {"A04","B04","CA6","DA6"},
};

var grouped = input.GroupBy(x => new { key1 = x[0], key2 = x[1] }, (keys, group) => new
{
    Key1 = keys.key1,
    Key2 = keys.key2,
    // skip(2) to prevent the keys to be added in the list
    Result = group.SelectMany(x => x.Skip(2)).ToList()
});
```

Output:

> { Key1 = "A01", Key2 = "B01", Result = ["CA1", "DA1, "CA2", "DA2"] }
>
> { Key1 => "A02", Key2 = "B02", Result = ["CA3", "DA3, "CA4", "DA4"] }
>
> { Key1 = "A03", Key2 = "B03", Result = ["CA5", "DA5"] }
>
> { Key1 = "A04", Key2 = "B04", Result = ["CA6", "DA6"] }

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've update my question try to make clearer, could you help please?